# Wikitude Phonegap iOS Plugin

Tags: ios6, phonegap-plugins, cordova-2.0.0, wikitude

I have configured the Wikitude iOS plugin as suggested here -

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/AugmentedReality-Wikitude/Plugin

However, during the compilation it is showing me build error - WTArchitechview.h not found in WTWikitiudePlugin.m file.

I am currently having iOS 6 device and using Cordova 2.0.0. I found one guide in the wikitude documentation -

http://forum.wikitude.com/documentation?p_p_id=2_WAR_knowledgebaseportlet&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-2&p_p_col_count=1&_2_WAR_knowledgebaseportlet_mvcPath=%2Fdisplay%2Fview_article.jsp&_2_WAR_knowledgebaseportlet_resourcePrimKey=128189

It says I have to remove the armv7s architecture and have to do some modification files. I was not able to understand that modification part. I mean which file I have to modify.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're having two problems.

The first is, that you have to download the Wikitude SDK from there website and then add the files from the SDK into your phonegap Xcode project (Follow the steps described in your first link). If you did this and still having compile time errors, make sure that either your user header search path from your Xcode project is set correctly or you copied the Wikitude SDK files into the folder which are already setup in the sample project. You can also remove the existing Wikitude SDK folder in your Xcode project and drag the one in, which you have downloaded.

The second link describes what you need to change in order to build your project with the Wikitude SDK in Xcode 4.5. You need to change this in your Xcode project settings. You have to do this because the Wikitude SDK needs some libraries which are not available for the armv7s architecture right now.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I did what you said, now I am getting this error message -

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_WTArchitectView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in WTWikitudePlugin.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Also, the second link which I posted is telling to do some changes in the code that I do not understand. In which file and what I have to modify.